# How to load javascript from external source and execute it in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, libraries

I am building some google apps scripts and want to load a javascript file located on one of my servers and be able to execute it's functions in Google Apps Script.

This way I can share a google apps script with people and update the javascript without effort needed from their side. (I would just update the version on my server which is then loaded in their Google Apps Script.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Would that not be cross-site scripting?

Comment: Also see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646554/importing-external-javascript-to-google-apps-script

Comment: Related:1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63647410 2. https://stackoverflow.com/q/73166361/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this:

```
eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch("my url").getContentText())
```

Although it would be a lot faster/more efficient to cache the code in CacheService and only fetch it fresh every 15 minutes or so.

Comment: @DanDas This is a significant modification to the original script and answer. I believe it'll benefit from a new answer. I also believe this edit should be rolled back.

Comment: @TheMaster: go ahead and be a stickler. Almost a year later when I had the same question, I'm happy my edit is [in the history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15549152/2). I don't see a need to pollute the question with an essentially identical answer, and I think a community wiki would be even better but don't want to take points away from Corey.