# How to use external javascript library Trello in google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, trello

I am trying to use Trello from a Google Spreadsheet (Google Docs) and am not sure how to import/reference/link the javascript files required to use their library.  My only other option is using their REST API directly (fine, but I'd rather use their js helper classes).

This is what Trello needs us to use:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://api.trello.com/1/client.js?key=substitutewithyourapplicationkey"</script>
```

How would I import/include these in a Google Apps Script?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/73166361/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115661/using-crypto-js-in-google-apps-script-what

Answer (score 51):

Based on the answer here by [Cameron Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731438/inject-external-javascript-file-in-google-app-scriptgoogle-docs#answer-26734725), you can use the eval() function on the appscript UrlFetchApp function.

```
eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://path.to/external/javascript.js').getContentText());
```

Comment: This is great. I was able to import moment.js into my Google Apps Script code like this: eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js').getContentText()); Then I was able to add a calendar entry like this:     //Add the years to the date
    var result = moment(date).add(numberOfYears, 'years').format("MMMM DD, YYYY");
    var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createAllDayEvent(' Deadline to for Whatever',
      new Date(result), {
        guests: 'GuitarViking@example.com',
        sendInvites: 'true'
      });

Answer (score 7):

you actually can . In the script project create another new file and simply just paste the JavaScript library copying from the source and save it then start referencing it from other file. It is that simple.

Or you can create another project with the .js lib and publish it and reference that script from the caller project, I wont do that unless that needs to be shared in multiple projects.

Comment: One thing to note, functions in other scripts are as if you concatenate them together. No need to import them or load them.

Answer (score 3):

Download them and put them in the script.
The rest api is easy to use. Ive used trello rest from appscript.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that but I downloaded source from the Trello API site and get the following when running the script (referring to the downloaded code):  "ReferenceError: "window" is not defined. (line 3, file "TrelloTools")Dismiss"

Comment: Google Apps Script is server side, so there is no window object.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use external javascript libraries this way in Google Apps Script. (You *can* do so in html files used with the [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service-caja#external_javascript_libraries). Since so much of Trello is client-side anyway, this may be just what you need.)

In server-side apps script, you should be able to access the library code using the technique from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15549152/1677912). It doesn't say, but I'd imagine that you would put that `eval` outside of all functions in your script, to make the objects in the library available to the rest of your code.

Comment: any specific examples of this?  I haven't been successful yet from a Google Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use JavasSript libraries in Google script. Copy all content of the libraries JavaScript and post it in new GS file.