# App script spreadsheets float calculation, can google app script do float point number calc?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, bigdecimal

Can google app script use external library in google app script that can do float number calculation, like bigdecimal?

when I do

```js
var i =  1.15 - 1.12 
console.log(i);
```

then `i = 0.029999999999999805`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer the question if it's possible, the answer is Yes, based on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646554/importing-external-javascript-to-google-apps-script).

However if you wanted to round it up to 2 decimal places only (or more), you don't have to resort to external library, use [Math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round):

```
function floatNumber(){

    var myInt =  1.15 - 1.12 ;
       myInt = Math.round(myInt * 100) / 100;
       Logger.log(myInt);
       //output 0.03
       //if you want 3 decimal places use /1000, and so on.
}
```