# "Window not defined" error when running google apps script (UrlFetchApp)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, trello

I am attempting to import the client.js library for the Trello API. 
This is so that I can use the Trello object and its methods in my code.

The error comes when I run this line:

```js
eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js').getContentText());
```

Is there anyway to fix this error/import this library? Or, because GAS is a server side, is it impossible?

Is there another way you suggest I go about importing this library?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `eval()` (which is evil and should rarely, if ever be used)?

Comment: The answer was suggested in this problem-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646554/importing-external-javascript-to-google-apps-script It was recommended I use this method.

Comment: you are mixing client code in server code. make sure you have both concepts clear beforehand. it is possible to use from gas.

Answer (score 0):

I believe jQuery requires access to the [document object model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), which is not available in GAS. You might want to consider using another library that does not depend on the existence of DOM, such as [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/).