# Copying range from google sheet to clipboard

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In the macro, I select a range in google sheet (this range can contain any type of data) and I want to copy it to the clipboard using the library Clipboard.js. How to do this ?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description  of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]

Comment: Possible duplicate [importing external javascript to google apps script]( https://stackoverflow.com/q/18646554/1595451)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [importing external javascript to google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646554/importing-external-javascript-to-google-apps-script)

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Script runs in Google's servers, not in your computer. There is no access to local resources like the clipboard.

To send spreadsheet data to Clipboard.js, you will have to open a dialog box or a sidebar. See the [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html) guide.

To access spreadsheet data from your JavaScript code, see the [client-server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) guide.