# JSSoup - SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, import, urlfetch, unexpected-token, jssoup

In my Apps Script add-on, I need to use an external library **JSSoup** for managing some HTML text. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646554/importing-external-javascript-to-google-apps-script#answer-33315754) to figure out how to add/import an external library in Apps Script. Then I added `eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://github.com/chishui/JSSoup/blob/master/lib/jssoup.js').getContentText();` in my script but it is throwing this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

No more logging available for this error. How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon checking the fetched content, it shows the all the page content rather than just the code. It is because you are getting all the content of that page, not just the code. Use the raw version instead by clicking the `Raw` icon and should redirect you to the correct link.

[image: raw]

#### Your command now should look like this:

`eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chishui/JSSoup/master/lib/jssoup.js').getContentText());`

#### Page vs Raw:

[image: difference]

#### Note:

- Although after getting the proper content, you will encounter another issue. For that, you might need to post another question here for others to answer that issue.

Comment: Thanks! It worked the same as you mentioned. I am getting this new error ```SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module```. Do you have any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: Hi @TanmayBairagi, I was not able to fix that import issue on my end. you might need to post another question for that one.