# Creating new user in Firebase using Google AppScript

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets, firebase-authentication

I'm calling Firebase from Google Apps Script.

I am able to connect to Firebase and read/write data using the Firebase Google Apps Script library here 
https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase

However this library doesn't seem to have support for the createUser functions. How should I create a new user in Firebase using Apps Script with the function createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)?

Here is what I'm trying to do in Google Apps Script -

```
function create_user(email, password) {
    var firebaseUrl = "https://myfb.firebaseio.com/";
    var secret = "mysecret";
    var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl, secret);

    base.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        Logger.log(errorMessage);
    }); 
}
```

Any advice appreciated.

Regards
Rahul

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the raw libraries instead of this wrapper script.
Use firebase.js client library directly:
https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6/firebase.js

[inject external javascript file in google app script(Google Docs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731438/inject-external-javascript-file-in-google-app-scriptgoogle-docs#answer-26734725)
shows you how to import the external library script.

You can then run your client code:

```
var config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaS...",
  authDomain: "xxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com"
}; 
firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)...
```

Comment: Thanks Bojeil. I tried your suggestion of injecting external js via eval. That line does not throw any error - great.

However, when I then try firebase.initiatlizeApp(config) it throws an error “firebase not defined”. How should I define/initialize firebase? 

If I try var ref = new Firebase(…), it gives me a timeout error on this line. 

Thanks in advance
Rahul

Comment: With `eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.1/firebase-app.js').getContentText()); eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.1/firebase-auth.js').getContentText());`, I got error `Error: The XMLHttpRequest compatibility library was not found.`